# How to check if a user is logged into Cisco NetAccess in VBA (Excel)?

Tags: excel, vba, networking, network-programming, network-connection

We use Cisco NetAccess to authenticate users who access various databases. The URL format is https://server:port/netaccess/loginuser.html. After logging in via a browser, it displays:

```
You are logged in.
Username: username
User IP: x.x.x.x
Since: hh:mm:ss xST ddd mmm d yyyy
```

The authentication has a duration of about 8 hours. This must be completed before signing into the front end app or querying the back end DB via Excel, Access, DbVis, etc.

We're building a dashboard in Excel that will query such a database. I'd like to write a VBA script that will check if the current user is logged into this authentication before attempting to query the DB. Is there a way to ping/query the server to see if the username and user IP are logged in?

Comment: It depends. If your Excel file runs on the server (and has good rights), via VBA you can launch a command line to query the logged users (depending on the OS of the server, for example it would be Bash if your server is Linux). That should be pretty easy. However, if your Excel file runs on an other computer, then either Cisco NetAccess provides an API to retrieve the connected users (which I would doubt, this would be an admin API of course, but I wouldn't distribute such a functionality externally), or I don't think it would be possible.

Comment: If your Excel file runs on another computer, alternatively to the API and admitting you know the server credentials, you may still use an utility such as plink (this is again for Linux, but there are others for other OS) to login and run a remote command to retrieve the users. But be aware that security-wise, hardcoding admin server credentials in an Excel macro is terrible.

Comment: Assuming a log is written (and it probably is/ can), I think I would prefer to query the log file from VBA.  Simpler, safer.